# how to create and write a temporary file in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a xml content and I want to write it in a temporary xml file and later prompt user to save it.I have this...

```
var xml_content = document.getElementById('content_xml').value;
var downloadable=encodeURIComponent(xml_content);
document.location= 'data:Application/octet-stream,' +downloadable;
```

please help me with a pure javascript code, I mean without jquery.

Comment: You can't do this; the file must be on the server.

Comment: ok...if I keep a static file on server, is that possible?

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/V7k8E/

Comment: i know my code works but.... the file does not have any extension...and it I keep it data:Application/xml it formatted as xml but does not prompt to save it.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use localstorage to achieve something similar

```
localStorage.setItem("tempxml", xml_content);
```

Then, for retrieving it (even when the user closed and reopened the browser):

```
var xml_content = localStorage.getItem("tempxml");
```

`localStorage` is available in recent browsers, contents are saved on user's browser data (client side of course).

Hope this helps. Cheers